# v-container won't align left

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm not able to align a v-container to the left side.
I used vu-cli3 3.9.0 & vuetify 1.5.5
Here is app.vue : https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-template-phfxu?fontsize=14

I have the same thing on my app and here is what it displays :

css : https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8pKk.gif
what it looks like on firefox : https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ruh1.gif

edit: here is more css : [more css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6wRO.gif)

Comment: please provide a running codepen like [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eqWKrL?editors=1010) in order to debug it

Comment: I think https://codesandbox.io/s/vue will be easier for you. But yeah, please provide running example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by placing import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css' as the last import.
The issue come back when I build and deploy the app but I guess it's a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to container:

```
...
<v-container class="margin-initial">
...
```

and in css

```
.margin-initial {
  margin: initial;
}
```

Or what ever other name. The trouble is with `margin: auto;` property as a default in `v-container`